# Show different web pages in multi view using link button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have developed a web site on ASp.net 3.5 with VB which have multiple pages the problem is i want to show all pages in one view user click on link button and coprresponding page should open on single page then user click to other link button and another page open in same browser window with same layout.Please suggest me what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You could use AJAX to achieve this. So for example let's suppose that you have multiple controller actions that return partial views. You could then create links on your page to those actions:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("page 1", "Page1", "SomeController", null, new { id = "link1" }) %>
<%= Html.ActionLink("page 2", "Page2", "SomeController", null, new { id = "link2" }) %>
<%= Html.ActionLink("page 3", "Page3", "SomeController", null, new { id = "link3" }) %>
```

and 3 corresponding placeholders where the pages would be loaded:

```
<div id="page1" />
<div id="page1" />
<div id="page1" />
```

you could now AJAXify those links in a separate javascript file. Example with jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#link1').click(function() {
        $('#page1').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
    $('#link2').click(function() {
        $('#page2').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
    $('#link3').click(function() {
        $('#page3').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

I would also strongly recommend you going through the [tutorials on the ASP.NET MVC site](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Comment: I am still unaware, kindly send more usefull example , i will be glad

Comment: @Asif khan, you are unaware of what? What happened when you tried to implement this?

Comment: Sir i am not old fellow of asp.net nor expereinced. kindly give simple solution of that, i will be pleased

Comment: @Asif khan, that's why I suggested you following the getting started tutorials on http://asp.net/mvc. Don't expect someone else writing the code for you. That's not how it works. So read the tutorials and try to implement it yourself. Then if you encounter some problems don't hesitate to ask here by showing what you have tried so far.